# Is the VDsat the same for these transistors?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Here is the circuit :

[image]

Can i say that the VDsat of transistors M1 and M1a is the same? And what about M3 and M3a?

Also can i say that the VDsat of M6 is equal to : VdsatM6 = VdsatM1a + VdsatM3a ?

Comment: yes,  if they are the same type of transistors with same Vth

Comment: Does that also applies to the VDsat of M6 ( VdsatM6 = VdsatM1a + VdsatM3a) ?

Comment: No, why do you think they're equal?

Comment: I was doing KVL and i was unsure if VdsatM6 would be only the sum of VdsatM1a and VdsatM3a or i should also sum the Vdsat of that pnp at above that has a corrent of 2I going through it